# Javascript value assignment somehow not working

Tags: javascript, properties, pixi.js

Im working with Pixi to create a Game and when I want to change a value, it just doesnt work

`towerRadius = u.circle(0, '#b75656', 0, 0, 0, 0);
towerRadius.blendMode = PIXI.BLEND_MODES.ADD;`

This is where I set the new sprite "circle". Later in the Code, I want to set the diameter of the circle new.

`towerRadius.diameter = 100;
console.log(towerRadius.diameter);`

the console always says 0. No matter what I do. towerRadius.diameter is not changing. I also tried towerRadius.radius.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the doc, the `Circle object` only has `radius` property. http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Circle.html. I'm not familiar with this library so I'm not sure if it answers to your question. Can you provide more information on your context ? Like the `u` object, where does it come from ?

Comment: Ah, right, I also tried to set the radius property, but that doesnt work too. The pixi docs are in my view not readable. I've never seen such bad and incomplete docs. The 'u' object is from pixi's spriteUtilies, a pixi plugin that creates shapes as sprites. the first argument of `u.circle()` is **diameter**

Comment: Which version of PIXI are you running ? Sprite Utilites seems to be working with v3 and didn't have any update since 2017. There isn't any info regarding v4. The author of this package still active on GitHub, I would encourage you to create an issue directly on the repo : https://github.com/kittykatattack/spriteUtilities/issues. Anyway, your usage seems to be correct according to the doc so I'm pretty sure something isn't working anymore with current version of PIXI. You could downgrade to v3.0.11 to verify if it's effectively the case.

Can't do much about this, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am not really used to Github, so I didnt know there is an 'issue Tab'.

Comment: You can try using the "scale" like this: towerRadius.scale.set(3, 3);

Comment: That just zooms in on the sprite, which just ends in bigger pixel, making the sprite blurred. But thanks anyway.